# Scala Console.readInt deprecated

Tags: scala

The command line interpreter of scala shows:

```
scala> Console.readInt
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res0: Int = 65
```

Is `Console.readInt` really deprecated? If yes, what is the correct way of taking input?

I am using Scala version 2.11.7 on OS X 10.10.5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Scala 2.11 you can use

```
scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
```

or

```
scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt
```

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by the REPL, run `scala -deprecation` to get more info:

```
scala -deprecation
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>  Console.readInt
<console>:8: warning: method readInt in class DeprecatedConsole is deprecated: Use the method in scala.io.StdIn
               Console.readInt
                       ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use import to depress the warning:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._
val name = readLine("Your name:")
val age = readInt()
printf("Your name: %s, your age: %d\n", name, age)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Scala Api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.Console$)

```
(Since version 2.11.0) Use the method in scala.io.StdIn
```

It also has `readInt` method